# How to apply gradient color across entire GridView

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview

Here's what I want the resultant gridview to look like:

[image]

Is there a way to automatically apply this across the entire gridview of containers?

Comment: I think it is using overlay with gradient, what is the use cases of it? just showing this view?

Comment: Yeah I wanted to make grid with 0-9 digits, like in a number dialler. The picture has a lot more containers, buts it's the closest I could find in relation to a gridview

Comment: You may look for CustomPaint or clipPath

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          child: GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: 4,
            children: List.generate(
              40,
              (index) {
                return Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              colors: [
                Colors.lightBlue,
                Colors.blue,
                Colors.pink,
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This only applies the gradient to the background container, not the actual gridview